# Why is there a type class Measured for Data.FingerTree instead of just a function?

Tags: haskell

I don't understand why `FingerTree` is implemented with the type class `Measured`.

I'm trying to implement a sequence of monoid that have the default measure the same as the monoid, so I wrote the following.

```
instance Monoid a => Measured (Sum Int, a) a where
  measure x = (Sum 1, x)
```

Of course, since `FingerTree` itself is a `Measured`, this is impossible as we will get type class overlap.

At what point was abstracting this single function into a type class make sense? Why can't we just define `FingerTree` so we can feed a measure function to the constructor?

It would also be nice to know if there are ways to overcome this problem. I could just define a new instance for my particular use case each time, but maybe there is a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an instance of the general friction between typeclass function resolution and "direct" function resolution. There are many times to favor direct, as you've pointed out here, but often times when it's possible to state particular laws that a typeclass instance must uphold people find it meaningful to use typeclass resolution.

I don't think it's possible to have a "right" answer for which is better, but there are indeed great arguments for using the direct method more frequently.

In this case, the more specificity is needed to help the compiler understand which instance should be resolved. While it's the case that any `Monoid` can have a "count and combine" `Measured` instance, it's not clear that this is the canonical instance. Since the class for `Measured` demands that `Measured v a | a -> v` we must pick `v` canonically.

The most likely way to do this is to create a `newtype` wrapper

```
newtype Counted a = Counted a
instance Monoid a => Measured (Sum Int, a) (Counted a) where
  measure (Counted x) = (Sum 1, x)
```

which gives us the required canonicity. This *might* be more convenient in some instances than passing around the `Monoid` function dictionary directly.